# Is the connection for the optocoupler on this PCB damaged?

Tags: pcb

[image]

The optocoupler slot is the six pin slot on top of the board in the picture that is empty. I was wondering if the missing rings around some of the pin holes will affect connection.

Answer (score 3):

- Top left: Doesn't matter, it's a No Connection (NC) pin
- Top right: Same thing, doesn't matter
- Middle left: Looks fine
- Middle right: Looks fine
- Bottom left: Probably fine if you solder carefully
- Bottom right: This one might be a problem, you might have to use a jumper wire to connect it to the via on the right of the pin